# Cannot open database “MSSQLSERVER” requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user sa

Tags: sql-server, vba

I'm fairly new to both SQL Server, as well as VBA. I'm trying to connect to our SQL Server using VBA and after troubleshooting several issues, I've finally hit a roadblock. I'm receiving the following error message:

> Cannot open database “MSSQLSERVER” requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user sa

I realize that using the `sa` username is not ideal for security purposes, but it's what I have to work with right now. I've tried restarting SQL Server, I've ensured that mixed mode authentication is on. The code I'm using is listed below, I'm just using a test query for now to pull one line of data from the db. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String

' Create the connection string.
sConnString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=servername;Database=MSSQLSERVER;Uid=sa;Pwd=password;"

' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

' Open the connection and execute.
conn.Open sConnString
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT IM_BARCOD.BARCOD FROM IM_BARCOD WHERE BARCOD = '793661061274';")

' Check we have data.
If Not rs.EOF Then
    ' Transfer result.
    Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
' Close the recordset
    rs.Close
Else
    MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
End If

' Clean up
If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: I really hope the password is NOT what you have in that connection string

Comment: Take the VBA piece out of the equation. Use SSMS or the UDL method to test connectivity. Can you connect at all with SSMS? If so, browse to the server logins and make sure sa is enabled

Comment: `MSSQLSERVER` is the default service name for the default (unnamed) instance - is that **really** your database name, also??

Comment: Don't use the 'sa' user for making connections.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009936/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server

Comment: I've already confirmed that sa is enabled and yes (oddly enough), MSSQLSERVER is the name of our instance - there was nothing else listed. And no, that's not my password...I'll try a couple of the suggestions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot open database **“MSSQLSERVER”** requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user sa

Database MSSQLSERVER does not exist, so it can't be open.

Just pass nothing as Database in your connection string, or pass `master`, or any existing database that you should use.

Answer (score 0):

sa user is disabled for logging by default, you need to enable it, try this:

https://sudeeptaganguly.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/how-to-enable-sa-account-in-sql-server/

Comment: Don't enable the 'sa' user. Disable it and rename it. That's best practice!